# Jquery event click html() only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that when clicking on the element should enter a textarea value, but the function works only by clicking once and then does not work anymore, unless loading the page. How to make the function work every time I click on the element?

I made the function in javascript, but this only works in Firefox and does not work in chrome, so I gave up and tried jquery

```
$("#element").click(function(){
    $("#nameidtextarea").html("<br>");
});
```

It was expected that when clicking on #element the value "<'br'>" will be inserted into the textarea

Comment: @EvikGhazarian — Really not.

Comment: $("#nameidtextarea").append("<br>");

Comment: You have to append BR instead of assign it to text area, `$("#nameidtextarea").html($("#nameidtextarea").html() + "<br>");`

Comment: @EvikGhazarian — Modifying the innerHTML of a textarea is a really bad idea. It only works until the user starts typing.

Comment: If textarea, use `val`. Try `$("#nameidtextarea").val($("#nameidtextarea").val()+"<br wait. are you going to insert br to textarea?

Comment: You are replacing content. Put console.log in click method and that will be called every time.

Comment: without the associated HTML this is more difficult to answer.  Please add that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML content of a textarea element is the *default* value, so using it will only change the value if it hasn't been changed by the user.

Do not use `html()` to modify the value of a form control. Use `val()`.

---

You are currently **setting** the value to `<br>`. That's a *replace* action, not an *insert* action.

If you want to insert the data and not erase the existing data, then you will need to read the current value, modify it, then set the new value back.

---

```
$("#element").click(function(){
    const old_value = $("#nameidtextarea").val();
    const new_value = old_value + "<br>";
    $("#nameidtextarea").val(new_value);
});
```